# Unity 5.x hangs on Assets Progress in "Compiling Scripts"

Tags: c#, monodevelop, unity-game-engine

I have recently upgraded to Unity 5.x from 4.x.

Unity 4.x is working perfectly fine while in Unity 5.x when I add a script in the project it starts to process for an infinity time for no reason.

On closing he project and re-opening it the "Assets Progress" freezes on "Compiling Scripts" at 50% progress forever. Nothing happens them

I am using macboook retina MGX72, 8GB RAM Core i5.

Comment: I strongly suggest installing latest patch. Unity 5.x had and still have many, many bugs.

Comment: I installed Unity 5.3.1p1, still facing the same issue.

Till making the project everything works fine. But as soon as I add a script in the project, it hangs forever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I had a cracked version before and had the file store somewhere(where I do not know). therefore this issue got resolved with I reinstalled complete OS. Then only the Unity3D started working well.

Answer (score 0):

Unity Generally Rebuilds the Scripts while going from 4.x to 5.x , and updates codes , I Strongly Recommend to use the latest Version of Unity , However to resolve the problem you can try to rebuild your project or making an unity 5 blank application and copying the existing files in assets directory from the earlier project's asset directory.

Let me know if it works , it have worked for me earlier.

Comment: I am making a new project from the scratch. Till making the project everything works fine. But as soon as I add a script in the project, it hangs forever